# ¿Qué tengo mal en este código de Python de CRUD?

Tags: python, mysql, crud, pycharm

LLevo una semana intentando resolver unos problemas que me dan varias funciones para buscar, Insertar, Editar y eliminar registros. Los problemas son variados, desde cursor cerrado hasta listas vacías por problemas con las consultas a MySql.

La parte de busqueda del controlador ya está solucionada. No entiendo por qué no me deja realizar las operaciones del crud. Me comentaron la posibilidad de usar un método lógico por medio de un estado donde estado = 1 significa agregado, estado = 2 significa editado y estado = 3 siginifica eliminado. Estaría agradecido si alguien pudiese darme consejos o soluciones ya que me está comiendo la cabeza. Si necesitan detalles más precisos pidanlos y los daré. Gracias de antemano

El código es el siguiente

capa de datos:

```
from datos.conexion import Conexion
from entidades.Departments import Departments
from entidades.Location import Location
from entidades.VwDepartment import VwDepartment

class Dt_Departamentos:

    def __init__(self):
        self._con = None
        self._cursor = None

    def listarDepartamentos(self):
        listaDepartamentos = []
        try:
            self._con = Conexion.getConnection()
            self._cursor = self._con.cursor()
            sql ="SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, l.city from Seguridad.VwDepartment as d inner join Seguridad.locations as l on d.location_id = l.location_id;"
            self._cursor.execute(sql)
            registros = self._cursor.fetchall()
            for r in registros:
                id = r['department_id']
                nombre = r['department_name']
                city= r['city']
                departamento = VwDepartment(id, nombre, city)
                listaDepartamentos.append(departamento)
            return listaDepartamentos
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error en la consulta", e)
        finally:
            Conexion.closeCursor()
            Conexion.closeConnection()

    def agregarDepartamento(self, departamento_param):
        resultado = False
        try:
            self._con = Conexion.getConnection()
            self._cursor = self._con.cursor()
            sql = f"UPDATE departments.department_id, departments.department_name, departments.location_id, locations.city " \
                  f"from Seguridad.locations inner join Seguridad.departments on locations.location_id = departments.location_id " \
                  f"where estado = 1;"
            if self._cursor.execute(sql) > 0:
                resultado = True
            self._con.commit()

        except Exception as e:
            print("Error en la consulta", e)
        finally:
            Conexion.closeCursor()
            Conexion.closeConnection()
            return resultado

    def validarIdUnico(self, department_id):
        resultado = False
        try:
            self._con = Conexion.getConnection()
            self._cursor = self._con.cursor()
            sql = f"SELECT department_id FROM Seguridad.departments WHERE department_id = '{department_id}';"
            if self._cursor.execute(sql) > 0:
                resultado = True
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error en la consulta", e)
        finally:
            Conexion.closeCursor()
            Conexion.closeConnection()
            return resultado

    def editarDepartamento(self, departamento_param):
        resultado = False
        try:
            con = Conexion.getConnection()
            cursor = Conexion.getCursor()
            sql = f"UPDATE Seguridad.departments SET department_name = '{departamento_param.department_name}', location_id = {departamento_param.location_id} WHERE department_id = '{departamento_param.department_id}';"
            if cursor.execute(sql) > 0:
                resultado = True
            con.commit()

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error en la actualizacion:, {e}")
        finally:
            Conexion.closeCursor()
            Conexion.closeConnection()
            return resultado

    def eliminarDepartamento(self, departamento_param):
        resultado = False
        try:
            con = Conexion.getConnection()
            cursor = Conexion.getCursor()
            sql = f"UPDATE Seguridad.departments set estado = 3;"
            if cursor.execute(sql) > 0:
                resultado = True
            con.commit()

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error en la eliminacion:, {e}")
        finally:
            Conexion.closeCursor()
            Conexion.closeConnection()
            return resultado

    def buscarDepartamento(self, departamento_param):
        listaDepartaments = []
        try:
            con = Conexion.getConnection()
            cursor = Conexion.getCursor()
            sql = f"SELECT VwDepartment.department_id, VwDepartment.department_name, VwDepartment.location_id, VwLocations.city " \
                  f"from Seguridad.VwLocations inner join Seguridad.VwDepartment on VwLocations.location_id = VwDepartment.location_id " \
                  f"where department_name like '%{departamento_param.department_name}%';"

            resultados = cursor.execute(sql)
            print(f"Resultados: {resultados}")

            registros = cursor.fetchall()
            for r in registros:
                id = r['department_id']
                nombre = r['department_name']
                city = r['city']
                vista = VwDepartment(id, nombre, city)
                listaDepartaments.append(vista)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error en la busqueda: {e}")
        finally:
            Conexion.closeCursor()
            Conexion.closeConnection()
            return listaDepartaments
```

El controlador es el siguiente:

```
class CtrlFrmDepartamentos(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
dDepartamento = Dt_Departamentos()
departamento = Departments()
dCiudad = Dt_Location()

def __init__(self):
    self.listaRegion = [] #guardar la lista de regiones(incluido su id) y poder usarlo en guardar, editar.
    super().__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_FrmDepartamentos()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.initControlGui()
    self.cargarDatosTabla()
    self.cargarDatosCombobox()

def initControlGui(self):
    self.ui.btn_agregar.clicked.connect(self.btnAgregar)
    self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    self.ui.btn_limpiar.clicked.connect(self.limpiarDatos)
    self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.clicked.connect(self.filaSeleccionada)
    QApplication.instance().focusChanged.connect(self.validarIdentificador)
    self.ui.btn_editar.clicked.connect(self.btnEditar)
    self.ui.btn_eliminar.clicked.connect(self.btnEliminar)
    self.ui.btn_buscar.clicked.connect(self.btnBuscar)
    self.ui.le_buscador.textChanged.connect(self.refresh)
    pass

def refresh(self):
    if self.ui.le_buscador.text() == "":
        self.cargarDatosTabla()

def validarIdentificador(self,old_widget, now_widget):

    if self.ui.le_identificador is old_widget:

        if self.ui.le_identificador.text() == "":
            return

        if len(self.ui.le_identificador.text()) > 2:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "El identificador no puede tener más de 2 caracteres")
            #self.ui.le_identificador.setFocus()
            return

def filaSeleccionada(self):
    if len(self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.selectedItems()) > 0:
        row = self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.selectedItems()[0].row()
        self.ui.le_identificador.setText(self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.item(row, 0).text())
        self.ui.le_nombre.setText(self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.item(row, 1).text())
        self.ui.cbx_localizacion.setCurrentText(self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.item(row, 2).text())
    self.ui.le_identificador.setEnabled(False)

def cargarDatosCombobox(self):
    dLocalizacion = Dt_Location()
    listaDepartamentos = dLocalizacion.listarLocations()
    self.listaCiudad = self.dCiudad.listarLocations()
    self.ui.cbx_localizacion.clear()
    self.ui.cbx_localizacion.addItem("---Seleccione---")
    for r in self.listaCiudad:
        self.ui.cbx_localizacion.addItem(r.city)

def cargarDatosTabla(self):
    dDepartamento = Dt_Departamentos()
    listaDepartamentos = dDepartamento.listarDepartamentos()
    self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.setRowCount(len(listaDepartamentos))

    if listaDepartamentos == None:
        alert = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Alerta', "No hay ningún departamento", QMessageBox.Ok)
        return

    self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.setRowCount(len(listaDepartamentos))
    self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.setColumnCount(3)
    self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
    row = 0
    for d in listaDepartamentos:
        self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(d.id_department)))
        self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(d.department_name))
        self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(d.city)))
        row += 1

def limpiarDatos(self):
    self.ui.le_identificador.setText("")
    self.ui.le_nombre.setText("")
    self.ui.cbx_localizacion.setCurrentIndex(0)
    self.ui.le_identificador.setEnabled(True)

def btnAgregar(self):
    if self.ui.le_nombre.text() == "" and self.ui.cbx_localizacion.currentIndex() == 0:
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "Ingrese los datos completos")
        return

    dDepartamento = Dt_Departamentos()
    d = Departments()
    d.department_id = self.ui.le_identificador.text()
    d.department_name = self.ui.le_nombre.text()
    index = self.ui.cbx_localizacion.currentIndex()
    d.city = self.listaCiudad[index - 1].city

    if not dDepartamento.agregarDepartamento(d):
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Érror", "No se pudo agregar el registro")
        return
    QMessageBox.information(self, "Éxito", "Se agregó el registro correctamente")
    self.limpiarDatos()
    self.cargarDatosTabla()

def obtenerRegionId(self, nombreRegion):
    for r in self.listaRegion:
        if r.region_name == nombreRegion:
            return r.region_id
    return -1

def btnEditar(self):
    if self.ui.le_identificador.text() == "":
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "Ingrese el identificador")
        return

    dDepartamento = Dt_Departamentos()
    d = Departments()
    d.department_id = self.ui.le_identificador.text()
    d.department_name = self.ui.le_nombre.text()
    index = self.ui.cbx_localizacion.currentIndex()
    d.city = self.listaCiudad[index - 1].city

    alert = QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Alerta', f"¿Está seguro de editar el departamento {d.department_name}?",
                                QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
    if alert == QMessageBox.No:
        return

    if not dDepartamento.editarDepartamento(d):
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Érror", "No se pudo editar el registro")
        return
    QMessageBox.information(self, "Éxito", "Se editó el registro correctamente")
    self.limpiarDatos()
    self.cargarDatosTabla()

def btnEliminar(self):
    if self.ui.le_identificador.text() == "":
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "Ingrese el identificador")
        return

    dDepartamento = Dt_Departamentos()
    d = Departments()
    d.department_id = self.ui.le_identificador.text()
    d.department_name = self.ui.le_nombre.text()

    alert = QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Alerta', f"¿Está seguro de eliminar el departamento {d.department_name}?",
                                QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
    if alert == QMessageBox.No:
        return

    if not dDepartamento.eliminarDepartamento(d):
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Érror", "No se pudo eliminar el registro")
        return
    QMessageBox.information(self, "Éxito", "Se eliminó el registro correctamente")
    self.limpiarDatos()
    self.cargarDatosTabla()

def btnBuscar(self):
    if self.ui.le_buscador.text() == "":
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "Ingrese el nombre del departamento")
        return

    self.departamento.department_name = self.ui.le_buscador.text()
    listaDepartamento = self.dDepartamento.buscarDepartamento(self.departamento)

    self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.setRowCount(len(listaDepartamento))
    self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.setColumnCount(3)
    self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
    row = 0
    for d in listaDepartamento:
        self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(d.id_department)))
        self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(d.department_name))
        self.ui.tw_registroDepartamentos.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(d.city)))
        row += 1
```